# How do I encode a single dictionary item to JSON in KDB?

Tags: kdb

In KDB:

```
.j.j `something`else!(1 2)
```

produces `{"something": 1, "else": 2}` as expected

However, doing

```
.j.j `something!1
```

just produces `,"1"`, with no labels.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this is a bug in `.j.j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enlist the keys and values in the dictionary

```
q).j.j enlist[`something]!enlist 1
"{\"something\":1}"
```

Otherwise your input is not a dictionary (type 99h), but an [enumeration](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enumeration/)

```
q)type `something!1
-20h
```